# Android client and Java server communicating on SSL Socket

Tags: java, android, ssl, tcp, ssl-certificate

**SERVER IMPLEMENTATION**

```
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    KeyManagerFactory kmf =  
    KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    char[] password = "daniere".toCharArray();
    ks.load(new FileInputStream("C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/keystore.jks"),password);
    kmf.init(ks,password);
    context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
    SSLServerSocketFactory factory = context.getServerSocketFactory();
    SSLServerSocket server = (SSLServerSocket)factory.createServerSocket(1000);
    System.out.println("Server ready for conncetions...");
    while (true)
    {
     SSLSocket soc = (SSLSocket) server.accept();
    BufferedReader key = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));

    String c = null;
        while((c=key.readLine())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(c);
            break;
        }

       }
```

**CLIENT IMPLEMENTATION**

```
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory =  TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/trust.bks");
    ks.load(in,"daniere".toCharArray());
    trustManagerFactory.init(ks);
    sslcontext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
    SSLSocketFactory sf = sslcontext.getSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket s1 = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket("10.0.0.1", 1000);
    String key = "sdsdsd";
    PrintWriter sockey = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s1.getOutputStream())), true);
    sockey.println(key);
    s1.close;
```

i have self created certificate and keystore an truststore. The Android client just has to authenticate if is speaking to the proper server.Client need not authenticate to the server.

**ERRORS**

Server ready for conncetions...

Server connected to :/10.0.0.2:45120  /10.0.0.1:1000

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at SSL.SSLserverThread.run(SSLserverThread.java:75)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more

I am not able to figure out why the client closes the socket at handshake?????
I have spent a lot of time  searching about this problem with no luck. I am new in this so

any help appreciated .

I tried this server/client ssl socket on pure java and it worker perfectly..
When try to implement on Android as a client no success.
Thanks alot.